# How to clear textbox in javascript that contains value of gridview row editing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-3.5, asp.net-4.0

I have following ASP controls: a textbox , a gridview, an update button, and a reset button.

When I click on the row editing button of a gridview row, then it fills the corresponding value in the textbox.

My problem is that when I click on the reset button, it does not clear the textbox value that comes from the gridview row.

```
function btnReset_onclick() {
   document.getElementById("<%= txtDescription.ClientID %>").value = "";
}

protected void GridViewExpenses_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
     lblExpenseDesc = GridViewExpenses.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("lblDescription") as Label;
     txtDescription.Text = lblExpenseDesc.Text;
}
```

How can I clear the textfield?

Comment: Are you actually using ASP.NET 3.5 or 4.0, or really both of them?

Comment: Where is your reset button? Is it standard 'cancel' button of grid edit element form? Or do you have EditTemplate in your grid and you have your own asp:button there? Or is the button written outside of the grid altogether? To be honest we need to see some of your aspx code to help you. Otherwise it is like asking someone how to fix your car without telling them what car it is...

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clearTextBox() {
        document.getElementById('<%= txtTest.ClientID %>').value = "";
    }
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtTest" runat="server" Text="blah blah blah" />
<input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="clearTextBox()" />
```

That works for me...

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

Remove the default edit button of the grid (remove the ShowEditButton="True" of CommandField) and add a **link button** inside another **itemTemplate**. Also set the **CommandName attribute** of edit link button **to edit** and (this will help the edit button to work as the default edit of the grid). Then **call the javascript** on edit link button's OnClientClick event and perform your logic there. Also place two other **link buttons for update and cancel**, should be placed inside an **EditItemTemplate** and **CommandName attribute** for each of them should be set to **update and cancel** correspondingly..

Refer code below to see the implementation,

Aspx Section,

```
     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit"
        OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Eval("sample1")%>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtValue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="edit" OnClientClick="return ClearText(this.id)"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="update"></asp:LinkButton>
                    &nbsp;
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtnCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="cancel"></asp:LinkButton>
                </EditItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Java Script section,

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ClearText(btnID)
    { 
        var txtID=btnID.replace("lnkBtnEdit","txtValue");          
        var txtValue=document.getElementById(txtID);            
        
        alert(txtID);
         
        txtValue.value="";
        
        return true;
    }
</script>
```

code behind,

```
    protected void GridView1_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        populate();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        //do update logic here
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        populate();
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        populate();
    }
```

Hope this helps you...

Comment: @Kunal Sobti, I guess you are using the default edit button of the grid view. If so clicking the edit button will show an update button as well as a cancel button. I guess you need to call the javascript fuction on the click of edit button. For doing so you have to use a custom button instead of default Edit button...